# how to write a signal to change a field in a model after another filed from another model is changed

Tags: django

I have a user model that has to go through several tasks such as completing their information, taking some tests, and interviews. So I added a progress level field that shows the user status at the moment. this is my model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    isPreRegistered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, choices=USER_ROLE_CHOICES, default=USER_ROLE_CHOICES[0][0])
    role_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='applicant')
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=13)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, default=None)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, default=None)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    personalInfo = models.OneToOneField(PersonalInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    contactInfo = models.OneToOneField(ContactInfo, on_delete=models.Case, null=True)
    eliteInfo = models.OneToOneField(EliteInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    progress_level = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, choices=USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS, default=USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS[0][0])
```

and there are multiple models which are connected to the user model using a foreign key relation.
this is one of the models I added here for instance:

```
class PsychologicInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    final_assessment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_approved = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    is_interviewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want to write a signal or a save method that does something like this:
if the is_interviewed field was True, change that progress_level to USER_ROLE_CHOICES[1][0]

I have no idea how to do this so thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `.save()` method of `PsychologicInfo`

```py
class PsychologicInfo:
    ...

    def save(self):
        super().save()
        if self.is_interviewed:
            self.user.role = USER_ROLE_CHOICES[1][0] # or enter value here
            self.user.save()
```

or you can use [Django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/).